# A tag "iniciantes" é uma meta-tag? Deve ser removida?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, meta-tags, tag-específica

Acabei de ver uma pergunta com a tag [iniciantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iniciantes). Me parece ser uma meta-tag. Deveria ser removida, ou há algum uso concreto para ela?

P.S. retagueei (?) [a pergunta em questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30380/215) (que, a propósito, me parece uma pergunta válida - ainda que à primeira vista pareça algo do âmbito do superuser, ela envolve sim questões de programação).

Comment: Tenho a impressão que tanto essa como [tag:aprendizagem-programação] deveriam ser removidas. Só não sei o que fazer com [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugu%C3%AAs-para-iniciantes-em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o). **Só não removi de todas por não saber o que fazer com essa questão já que o número de questões é pequeno.**

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Acho que está na hora de rediscutirmos se a pergunta/resposta que você linkou deve permanecer no site ou não. [Eu acho ela muito esquisita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/990). Pra mim as duas tags são meta-tags, e desnecessárias.

Comment: @bfavaretto talvez o ideal seria transferir ela para o meta / FAQ. Ou excluí-la de uma vez. Meu "medo" que o fato dela ter bastante votos e usar tags esotéricas pode incentivar perguntas que não queremos por aqui.

Answer (score 9):

As tags [iniciantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iniciantes) e [aprendizagem-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) foram removidas de todas as perguntas, e serão apagadas em 24h

Answer (score 8):

> Deve ser removida?

## Sim, por favor!

*Solta o Trog nela!*

[image: Trogdor the Burninator]

Comment: O que nos traz à pergunta: Precisamos de uma tag "`burninate-request`"?

Comment: Eu tava só esperando a hora em que alguém ia trazer isso pra cá :)

Comment: Se "burninarmos" as duas tags, aquela pergunta-problema fica órfã de tags. Então o caso aqui é mais complicado.

Comment: Coisa de site grande, sô :o) . . . bom, tem a [tag:princípios-de-programação] pra adotar a orfã...

Comment: @bfavaretto ou então deixa mais claro como aquela pergunta é *off-topic*. Se não há uma *tag* que sirva nela, o problema está na pergunta. Até já foi oficializado uma solução para o tipo de conteúdo que tem nela. Deixá-la no site é pura teimosia.