# Priorizar o link de Tags em vez do Question Ban na página de ajuda

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Acho que o uso das Tags é mais relevante ao site do que o Bloqueio de Usuários (acredito que em sites pequenos são poucas ocorrências). Atualmente é assim na [página de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help):

> [image]

Minha sugestão é passar o link **O que são tags e como devo usá-las?**, que está dentro do
[**» Veja mais**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) para essa posição.

A discussão nos comentários [desta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1877/201) também me deu a idéia de que deveriamos dar mais destaque na página de Ajuda/Tags à importância da Wiki de Tags, um pouco do papel que está fazendo a pergunta [Material em português para iniciantes em programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugu%C3%AAs-para-iniciantes-em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) no site principal. Algo do tipo:

> [image]

Comment: Não sei o quanto é factível fazer só no SOpt, mas acho que vários itens mereciam uma nova ordem.