# Vamos remover o "[Iniciante]" ou "[resolvido]" no título de perguntas?

Tags: debate

Vi que o site tem várias perguntas com o termo ["[Iniciante]"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22%5Biniciante%5D%22) ou ["[Resolvido]"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22%5Bresolvido%5D%22) no título. Podemos fazer um mutirão para editar e resolver isso?

Já tivemos problemas parecido com este em [tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1877/a-tag-iniciantes-%c3%a9-uma-meta-tag-deve-ser-removida).

Relacionado:

- ["[Resolvido]" em título de pergunta não fica parecendo coisa de fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5389/resolvido-em-t%c3%adtulo-de-pergunta-n%c3%a3o-fica-parecendo-coisa-de-f%c3%b3rum)

Comment: Sempre que encontro meta-tag no título eu retiro.

Comment: Não sou contra, mas também não acho que valha o esforço. Quem tiver tempo livre, vai fundo, estará contribuindo com a comunidade, eu agradeço

Comment: No caso de "iniciante", não sei, tem muita coisa antiga - e ruim - que talvez nem valha a pena trazer pra home (se for o caso, só fecha pro sistema apagar automaticamente), sem contar que muitas não consegui pensar num título melhor (muitas são "iniciante em [linguagem/tecnologia]" e a dúvida é tão genérica que nem dá pra extrair um título decente). Quanto ao "resolvido", esse é mais fácil de remover...

Comment: Esse foi o meu caso, por isso ele fez o questionamento, eu me enquadro na situação de iniciante, por isso havia colocado, até questionei se poderia ser posto algo no lugar de iniciante ou se bastaria somente manter retirado. 
De qualquer forma segue a orientação que melhor se enquadrar com a comunidade.

Comment: Acho que se a pessoa é iniciante ou não, isso não faz diferença para a comunidade. No geral, o título da pergunta precisa ter relação com a dúvida. Claro que tem muitas perguntas que são parecidas com um "helpdesk", mas não é o ideal. Acredito que uma pergunta genérica, que vá servir para outras pessoas, não tem necessidade de ter essas "pseudo-tags" no título.

Comment: Tem como automatizar (acho eu) isso na plataforma e bloquear que o usuário faça tal edição: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7752/5878

Comment: @HyagoSantos O que importa é a dúvida do ponto de vista técnico. Lembre-se que a ideia do site é criar um repositório de conhecimento que seja útil não só para quem perguntou, mas para qualquer visitante futuro que tenha o mesmo problema. Uma das premissas do site é que as pessoas encontrem o que procuram, por isso o título tem que deixar claro qual é o problema, para que alguém com o mesmo problema encontre facilmente a resposta (por isso que "_Como fazer X na situação Y?_" é melhor do que "*Dúvida iniciante em X*"). Adicionar "iniciante" no título só acrescenta ruído e não ajuda na indexação

Comment: @hkotsubo, entendi perfeitamente, com essas dicas irei melhorar meus títulos das perguntas.

Comment: Pode valer sim o esforço se toda comunidade ativa policiar, mais pessoas atuando menos problemas.

Comment: Count me in. [Primeira contribuição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/490489/revisions) para o esforço.

Comment: Feito [3 edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=activity&sort=revisions), não farei mais que isso por hora para evitar poluir a home, formulei um texto básico para o motivo da edição, a quem interessar (ps: eu uso o autocomplete do navegador para ter o texto rápido): `Não escreva RESOLVIDO no titulo, marque a resposta com ✔️ que resolveu o seu problema, ou se foi você mesmo que resolveu crie uma resposta.`